# GetRecipientView: REST API Error ACCOUNT_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_ENVELOPE

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to get recipient url but getting "GetRecipientView REST Error ACCOUNT_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_ENVELOPE #44".

First I am creating the envelope to get sender url. And then I calling GetRecipientView() to get recipient view url. Below is the code I am using

```
    public string EmbeddedSenderView(string docId)
    {
        Account account = InitializeDocSign();

        Envelope envelope = new Envelope();
        envelope.Login = account;
        envelope.EmailSubject = "Please sign document";
        envelope.Recipients = new Recipients()
        {
            signers = new Signer[]
            {
                new Signer()
                {
                    email = "xxxx@gmail.com",
                    name = "AV Gmail 1",
                    routingOrder = "1",
                    recipientId = "1",
                    roleName="Signer",
                    clientUserId="101"
                },
            },
        };           
        envelope.Create("\FAQ_NMS.pdf");

        bool result = envelope.GetSenderView("my domain");          

        /*Saving document details into Database*/
        if (result)
        {                
            ObjDocumentSignRequest obj = new ObjDocumentSignRequest();
            obj.DocumentId = docId;
            obj.EnvelopeId = envelope.EnvelopeId;
            obj.SenderViewUrl = envelope.SenderViewUrl;
            eSignUtilities.SaveSignRequest(obj);           
        }
        return envelope.SenderViewUrl;
    }


    public void EmbeddedRecepientView(string docId)
    {
        Account account = InitializeDocSign();

        Envelope envelope = new Envelope();
        envelope.Login = account;
        envelope.EmailSubject = "Please sign document";
        envelope.Recipients = new Recipients()
        {
            signers = new Signer[]
            {
                new Signer()
                {
                    email = "xxxx@gmail.com",
                    name = "AV Gmail 1",
                    routingOrder = "1",
                    recipientId = "1",
                    roleName="Signer",
                    clientUserId="101"
                },
            },
        };

        envelope.EnvelopeId = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
        envelope.UpdateStatus();

        bool result = envelope.GetRecipientView("my domain");
```

Any help?

Thanks
AV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It resolved by using "GetEmbeddedSignerView" method

```
        Account account = InitializeDocSign();                   
        Envelope envelope = new Envelope();
        envelope.Login = account;
        // assign the envelope id that was passed in
        envelope.EnvelopeId = "xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxxx";         

        var signer = new Signer
        {
            email = "xxxxx@gmail.com",
            name = "AV xxxx 1",
            clientUserId = "101",
            recipientId = "1"
        };
        // generate the recipient view token
        string signingUrl = envelope.GetEmbeddedSignerView("http://www.google.com", signer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the envelope before you can request the signing URL (aka recipient view).  It looks like you are creating the envelope, generating the embedded sending URL, then trying to generate the embedded signing URL right after that.

I see before you call `GetRecipientView()` that you are calling

```
envelope.UpdateStatus();
```

However, I don't see you set

```
envelope.Status = "sent";
```

...anywhere before that, which means you are requesting an embedded signing URL on an envelope which is in the *draft* state, which will generate an error.